# MX:DividedBox Dynamic Panels Addition and Subtraction

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a divided box that has 3 panels in it... when a certain tab in tab navigator is clicked, then the sidebar with the three panels changed.  One tab might show one Panel, another tab might show two of the panels and so on.

I can turn panels invisible and hide the dividers and ever almost positions the panels right, but the dividers still exists so it's not as dynamic as I would like.

Is their an easier way to add and remove panels from the Divided box that won't take as much manual configuration and hacking to make look right?

The problem is once I hide a panel the divider still exists.

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing what is displayed, what you want to hide, and when you want to hide it.  A picture might help me.  ( Perhaps others too) and/or some code.

Comment: I'll +1 for the picture; I think it helps explains things much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do that with `removeChild()` and `addChild()`? See [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62b90-7fe9.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62b90-7fe5) and [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62b90-7fe9.html#WS2AD35652-B62C-46fb-93DD-853582281180) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the .includeInLayout property. Set the panel you want to hide `visible=false` AND `includeInLayout=false` and you should have no problem.